# Drop Down Box and other stuff in ASP.NET with VB.NET (VS 2008)

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2008

I am trying to polish up a program a program that I have converted from a Windows Form in to an ASP.NET Web Application.  I have several questions:

1.)  I have a drop down box where users can select their variables, but users can also enter their variables manually into various text fields.  What I want is for the drop down box to show a string like "Choose Variables" when ever the user enters their variables manually.  I want this to happen without having to reload the page.

2.)  In the Windows Form version of this application I had a RichTextBox that populated with data (line by line) after a calculation was made.  I used "AppendText" in my Windows Form, but that is not available in ASP.NET, and neither is the RichTextBox.  I am open to suggestions here, I tried to use just a text box but that isn't working right.

3.)  In my Windows Form application I was using "KeyPress" events to prevent incorrect characters from being entered into the text fields.  My code for these events looked similar to this:

```
Private Sub TextBox_KeyPress(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs) Handles TextBox.KeyPress

        If (e.KeyChar < "0" OrElse e.KeyChar > "9") AndAlso e.KeyChar <> ControlChars.Back AndAlso e.KeyChar <> "." Then
            e.Handled = True
        End If

End Sub
```

How can I make this work again... also without reloading the page.

4.)  This is not a major issue, but I would like all of the text to be selected when the cursor enters a field.  In my Windows Form application I used "SelectAll", but again, that is not available in ASP.NET

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How much of your hourly wage are you going to kick back to us?  Get more specific with your questions and you're more likely to get a helpful response.

Comment: You ported an entire application to ASP.Net without knowing what Javascript is? Wow...

Comment: This is homework guys so I have no money to offer, but you can have some of my school debt. I am learning so take it easy please. I know what Javascript is I just wasn't getting understanding your vauge statements. As for how specific my questions were, well I think they were specific enough to get my point across.  I now know that the events I want to handle need to be taken care of client side with javascript.  Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: If this is homework, the course is poorly taught.  I apologize; I didn't mean to insult you.

Comment: I cannot disagree there (about the quality of hte course), if no insult was intended then none was perceived. I am actually going above and beyond what the assignment requires, so I don't really need to handle client side events, but I like my work to be awesome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) You will have to do this in Javascript by changing the text of the dropdown or disabling it from the TextChanged event using something like [this](http://www.codetoad.com/javascript/enable_disable_form_element.asp)

2)You can use a Textbox with the TextMode set to MultiLine.  Then you can use Textbox1.Text = Textbox1.Text & newString to append text to the end.

3) You can either do this in javascript or by using a regular expression validator (my suggestion).

4) Do this in javascript using something like [this](http://www.java2s.com/Code/JavaScript/Form-Control/SelectingTextUponFocus.htm)

Answer (score 2):

You need to learn Javascript.

You should read a good book about it; asking us to write all of your Javascript code without learning the language is not a good idea.

Comment: Javascript? I think you read my question wrong. I am not asking for you to write my code either, I just don't know many ASP.NET functions, thus I am having trouble porting my Windows Form application correctly. Additionally, I have most of it working myself thank you very much. As I stated in my question, I am looking to polish it up a bit.  Here I was thinking SO was the place to ask these types of questions.

Comment: ASP.Net code runs in the server and cannot run without a postback (or AJAX callback).  In order to control behavior or run code in the browser, you _need_ to use Javascript.

Comment: Ok, that makes more sense than just saying "You need to learn Javascirpt".  I do recall seeing some AJAX functions in the toolbox.  I will investigate those here real quick.

Comment: AJAX is the wrong thing to use here and will result in a slow and unresponsive site. You _do_ need to use Javascript.

Comment: SLaks is right you really need to use javascript using AJAX controls will get you halfway there at best.

Comment: I have never used either so I will start with Javascript like you guys are suggesting.

Comment: Cool google "jQuery for ASP.NET Developers" I think this book should get you started.

Answer (score 0):

You need to start looking at client side scripting i.e. javascript.
This is the only way I know of to accomplish what you want with out posting back to the server.

There are some great javascript libraries out there:
[Jquery](http://jquery.com/) seems to becoming the defacto standard though. (Some may disagree with the defacto bit.) Jquery has some great example code on there site and lots of information is avaliable on the web. Good Hunting!